# Home wifi disconnects despite full signal strength

Tags: wireless-networking

I'm having a weird problem with my home wifi network:

One specific desktop PC's wifi connection is very unreliable. The signal strength appears full but the network often disconnects - sometimes a few times an hour, sometimes within mere seconds. Even while connected, any zoom / remote work is basically impossible - slow and jittery.

Replaced several wifi dongles, no real difference. Current one is 802.11ac connected @ 5GHz, slight improvement over the previous 802.11n dongle @ 2.4GHz

The PC is Windows 10, fully updated, some 6-7 meters (~20 ft) from the router with only a drywall between them. Other PCs in the house do not suffer from this issue.

Possibly related - The IPTV set top box sometimes becomes unwatchable with play skipping all the time (the IPTV is an Android box). Strangely, the IPTV built-in Netflix client is never affected, only the TV and VOD streams.

Connecting either the TV box or the desktop to phone wifi hotspot = smooth sailing.

The router is Tp-Link Archer VR600. The same thing used to happen on the previous (also Tp-Link, 802.11n, don't recall the exact model) router too.

Pinging the router from the problematic machine gives:

```
Pinging 192.168.1.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=2380ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=2852ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=10ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1918ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=2792ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=6ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
...

Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 1ms, Maximum = 2852ms, Average = 312ms
^C
```

Any ideas why this could be happening and/or how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: *"Replaced several wifi dongles ..."* -- Do you mean USB WiFi adapters?  Since only *"one specific desktop PC"* seems to be affected, I would first focus on the reception path to the WAP.  If you cannot relocate and/or re-orient the PC, then add a short half-meter USB extension cable, and try different locations & orientations for just the dongle.  Also, for a sanity test, relocate this PC to some verified optimal location for reception, and confirm that this PC itself has no WiFi issues.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the description and the ping response the most likely issue here is non-Wi-Fi interference. Unfortunately the source can't be identified without a very expensive Spectrum Analyzer. The list of possible sources is long and ever-growing, including radio-controlled doors, alarm systems, RADAR, even certain types of lighting installations.

Start by swapping the 5GHz radio (ac) to another channel. Non-Wi-Fi interference is usually very narrow band:

[image: interference]

... so just swapping to next channel usually is enough. However you might have to try a few before you hit an interference-free one - usually not, though.